# The function disappear close to zero

Tags: gnuplot

I have problem with plotting fitted function.

The part of the ploted function close to zero disappears and connected with the hyperbola or something which should not be there at all. This happen only if I change `set xrange` to something smaller than 0. I have to do this because I have lot of data points to close zero so it would look very ugly if I would not changed it.

I tried to use conditionals `x>0?f(x):1/0` but it does not help. The hyperbola disappear but the function does not continue down as it should.

I use this code:

```
set terminal postscript eps size 3.5,2.62 enhanced color

set output "a.eps"

set xrange [-1:]

f(x)=a*b*x/(1+a*x)

fit f(x) "./a" via a, b

plot "./a" w p title "", f(x) w l title "Langmuir isotherm"
```

Comment: Nobody is going to be able to test this unless you also make your data file `./a` available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is simply a matter of sampling. The default sampling rate is `100` (`show samples`), which isn't enough to show fast-varying functions. Increase the sampling rate with e.g.

```
set samples 1000
```

to have your function plotted correctly.

A second point is, that discontinuities aren't shown properly if no sample is located exactly at that position. Consider the following plot to demonstrate this:

```
set xrange [-1:1]

set multiplot layout 2,1
set samples 100
plot 1/x

set samples 101
plot 1/x
unset multiplot
```

[image]

So, if you want to plot the function correctly on both sides of the discontinuity, you must either define a small region around the discontinuity as undefined, or you plot the parts on the left and right  separately:

```
set xrange [-1:]    
f(x)=a*b*x/(1+a*x)
fit f(x) "./a" via a, b
left(x) = (x < -1/a ? f(x) : 1/0)
right(x) = (x > -1/a ? f(x) : 1/0)
plot "./a" w p title "", left(x) w l lt 2 title "Langmuir isotherm", right(x) w l lt 2 notitle
```