# Problems evaluating log function near 0 in a plot- Gnuplot

Tags: function, plot, gnuplot

I'm plotting the graph of `log(x)`, which is actually `ln(x)` in gnuplot with the command

```
%commands here...%
p [-5:40][-5:20] log(x)
```

The result is
[image: log]
My problem is that I would like to plot more values of the function, at least down to -5. I tried setting the ranges but nothing. Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35728093/2604213

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem!